# Spring Cloud Gateway not Working on Docker

Tags: java, docker, docker-compose, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I have configured a spring cloud gateway to redirect to a server a created with the following route:

```
@Bean
public RouteLocator myRoutes(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
    return builder.routes()
            .route(p -> p
                    .path("/v1/**")
                    .uri("lb://data-diff-service"))
            .build();
}
```

It works fine on a local environment, but when I start my services containers through my docker-compose file, the gateway is not able to find the customer-service.
It works fine when running locally outside the containers

[my docker-compose file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UoBDL.png)

```
version: "3.4"
services:
  registry-service:
    image:  project/registry-service
    hostname: registry-service
    ports:
      - "8761:8761"

  gateway:
    image: project/gateway
    hostname: gateway
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      EUREKA_CLIENT_SERVICEURL_DEFAULTZONE: http://registry-service:8761/eureka

  data-diff-service:
    image: project/data-diff-service
    hostname: data-diff-service
    environment:
      EUREKA_CLIENT_SERVICEURL_DEFAULTZONE: http://registry-service:8761/eureka
      SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_URI: mongodb://teste:teste@mongo-database:27017/data_diff?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

I'm testing it on the localhost 8080 port.
The data-diff-service can communicate normally with Mongo db that runs in a separate container

**EDIT**
result from http://:8761/eureka/apps:

```
<applications>
  <versions__delta>1</versions__delta>
  <apps__hashcode>UP_2_</apps__hashcode>
  <application>
    <name>GATEWAY</name>
    <instance>
      <instanceId>gateway:localhost:2ba2ecb7caf0931ba4b5580138cd3817</instanceId>
      <hostName>localhost</hostName>
      <app>GATEWAY</app>
      <ipAddr>172.20.0.4</ipAddr>
      <status>UP</status>
      <overriddenstatus>UNKNOWN</overriddenstatus>
      <port enabled="true">8080</port>
      <securePort enabled="false">443</securePort>
      <countryId>1</countryId>
      <dataCenterInfo class="com.netflix.appinfo.InstanceInfo$DefaultDataCenterInfo">
        <name>MyOwn</name>
      </dataCenterInfo>
      <leaseInfo>
        <renewalIntervalInSecs>30</renewalIntervalInSecs>
        <durationInSecs>90</durationInSecs>
        <registrationTimestamp>1615821410991</registrationTimestamp>
        <lastRenewalTimestamp>1615821560153</lastRenewalTimestamp>
        <evictionTimestamp>0</evictionTimestamp>
        <serviceUpTimestamp>1615821410308</serviceUpTimestamp>
      </leaseInfo>
      <metadata>
        <management.port>8080</management.port>
      </metadata>
      <homePageUrl>http://localhost:8080/</homePageUrl>
      <statusPageUrl>http://localhost:8080/actuator/info</statusPageUrl>
      <healthCheckUrl>http://localhost:8080/actuator/health</healthCheckUrl>
      <vipAddress>gateway</vipAddress>
      <secureVipAddress>gateway</secureVipAddress>
      <isCoordinatingDiscoveryServer>false</isCoordinatingDiscoveryServer>
      <lastUpdatedTimestamp>1615821410991</lastUpdatedTimestamp>
      <lastDirtyTimestamp>1615821410126</lastDirtyTimestamp>
      <actionType>ADDED</actionType>
    </instance>
  </application>
  <application>
    <name>DATA-DIFF-SERVICE</name>
    <instance>
      <instanceId>data-diff-service:localhost:2477c80c3a1b51f6af76fc02013be957</instanceId>
      <hostName>localhost</hostName>
      <app>DATA-DIFF-SERVICE</app>
      <ipAddr>172.20.0.5</ipAddr>
      <status>UP</status>
      <overriddenstatus>UNKNOWN</overriddenstatus>
      <port enabled="true">37069</port>
      <securePort enabled="false">443</securePort>
      <countryId>1</countryId>
      <dataCenterInfo class="com.netflix.appinfo.InstanceInfo$DefaultDataCenterInfo">
        <name>MyOwn</name>
      </dataCenterInfo>
      <leaseInfo>
        <renewalIntervalInSecs>30</renewalIntervalInSecs>
        <durationInSecs>90</durationInSecs>
        <registrationTimestamp>1615821441412</registrationTimestamp>
        <lastRenewalTimestamp>1615821441412</lastRenewalTimestamp>
        <evictionTimestamp>0</evictionTimestamp>
        <serviceUpTimestamp>1615821440902</serviceUpTimestamp>
      </leaseInfo>
      <metadata class="java.util.Collections$EmptyMap"/>
      <homePageUrl>http://localhost:37069/</homePageUrl>
      <statusPageUrl>http://localhost:37069/actuator/info</statusPageUrl>
      <healthCheckUrl>http://localhost:37069/actuator/health</healthCheckUrl>
      <vipAddress>data-diff-service</vipAddress>
      <secureVipAddress>data-diff-service</secureVipAddress>
      <isCoordinatingDiscoveryServer>false</isCoordinatingDiscoveryServer>
      <lastUpdatedTimestamp>1615821441412</lastUpdatedTimestamp>
      <lastDirtyTimestamp>1615821440865</lastDirtyTimestamp>
      <actionType>ADDED</actionType>
    </instance>
  </application>
</applications>
```

I've lost a day on it, could anyone help?

Comment: what does http://<eureka>:8761/eureka/apps say about the two services (Add it to your question)? Likely that they have registered with an internal IP address and you need to change that.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I've added it in the EDIT part. Is anything wrong with it?

Comment: localhost isn't going to work as a hostname, you'll have to set `eureka.instance.preferIpAddress=true`. Is a `172.*.*.*` IP address local or public?

Comment: Yes, I'm running it on my local machine so I assume It's local

Do I have to set this on each service(diff-service, gateway and registry-service)? : 
 `eureka.instance.preferIpAddress=true`

And what should I include in the `eureka.instance.hostname`
Can I use the `spring.aplication.name` ?

Comment: set prefer ip address on all services that register with eureka. Hostname won't matter after that. 172 addresses are private I think. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-commons/docs/3.0.1/reference/html/#ignore-network-interfaces for hints. Also https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bspring-cloud%5D+docker