# Spring Cloud Gateway + Eureka + Docker not routing properly

Tags: spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-gateway

I have a similar question to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66639877/spring-cloud-gateway-not-working-on-docker). It remains unanswered...

I have an Eureka server, a Spring Cloud gateway and other Spring-based services. When I put everything to run on local, it goes just fine.

Now, I'm trying to put everything in containers. I've figured out how to make the business services services and the gateway reach the eureka server. But now I'm facing a problem when the gateway tries to route to the other services. The route from the spring gateway to access the business service is wrong.

The gateway's application.yml. As you can see, it uses the load-balancer uri:

```
server:
  port: 8080
spring:
  application:
    name: api-gateway
  cloud:
    gateway:
      discovery:
        locator:
          enabled: true
      routes:
        - id: cognito
          uri: lb://cognito
          predicates:
            - Path=/cognito/**
          filters:
            - RewritePath=/cognito/(?<path>.*), /$\{path}
```

The docker-compose.yml. The onliest place in all files where [host.docker.internal] is written is here:

```
services:
  apigateway:
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    command: mvn clean spring-boot:run
    links:
      - "eureka"
    depends_on:
      - "eureka"
    environment:
      server.port: 8080
      eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone: http://host.docker.internal:8761/eureka
  eureka:
    ports:
      - "8761:8761"
    command: mvn clean spring-boot:run
    ports:
      - "8085:8085"
    command: mvn clean spring-boot:run
    links:
      - "eureka"
    depends_on:
      - "eureka"
environment:
  server.port: 8085
  eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone: http://host.docker.internal:8761/eureka
```

What's happening during execution:

```
apigateway_1  | java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not create URI object: Malformed IPv6 address at index 8: http://[host.docker.internal:8761]:8085/auth
apigateway_1  |         at org.springframework.web.util.HierarchicalUriComponents.toUri(HierarchicalUriComponents.java:521) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
apigateway_1  |         Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException:
apigateway_1  | Error has been observed at the following site(s):
apigateway_1  |         |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.WeightCalculatorWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
apigateway_1  |         |_ checkpoint ⇢ HTTP POST "/cognito/auth" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]
```

The eureka+spring gateway duo isn't routing correctly to the cognito container's address correctly.
**How to correct it????**

Comment: I'm using Docker for Windows if it matters..

Answer (score 1):

The problem was at the application.yml of the cognito service. There I was choosing the name of the instance and I shouldn't. I should use only the preferIpAddress=true.

Before:

```
eureka:
    instance:
        hostname: localhost
```

After:

```
eureka:
    instance:
        preferIpAddress: true
```

And the docker-compose.yml I've put the hostname for the eureka service (let's say: eureka-service) and then added the environment var `eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone: http://eureka-service:8761/eureka`

That's it!